# OpenEdge: Get clicked column in a browser

Tags: browser, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a browser object and I'm trying to get the number of the column in which the user clicked a cell - is that possible? My browser is called **brw-misc** so when I try:

```
brw-misc:CURRENT-COLUMN
```

I get '?' in return unless I've clicked on the column heading to sort the records before that.

```
brw-misc:COLUMN
```

Always returns '1'.

Answer (score 2):

The **CURRENT-COLUMN** attribute only works with editable browsers. That's probably why you're getting a null (?). The **COLUMN** attribute is where the browser is positioned on the frame.

If the browser is editable, you can use

```
brw-misc:CURRENT-COLUMN:LABEL
```

to get the column label. You can then use that to figure out which column number that is.

Comment: I'd use a different attribute than LABEL, it is translation dependent. The NAME attribute would be better. If the browse contains calculated field make sure to display them @ variablename otherwise the name attribute is unknown

Answer (score 1):

TheDrooper offered some good advice above.

If that column is editable, and clicking it actually gets inside the field (to update the value), then you can query FOCUS:NAME to learn what is the column name you just clicked. It's a handle, all handle attributes apply.

It's going to be way trickier if you don't have the fields enabled, though. You didn't specify if this is client GUI, I'll go ahead and assume it is (rather than Webspeed). You need to capture mouse coordinates using Windows DLLs, your window coordinates (using X and Y attributes), then your browse columns X and Y, and hope that browse is not horizontally scrollable, lol.

If you do all that, you can tell which column they clicked on. Oh, and since (As far as I understood) you're more worried on which column he clicked on, rather than which cell, you're going to value X over Y (but don't forget to test to make sure they actually clicked INSIDE the browse at all).

Off the top of my mind, that's what I can think of. Not sure if it helps, but it might point you somewhere!